# Modular Arithmetic Exponentiation Rule

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Just wondering how one would go about using the exponentiation rule for modular arithmetic?

Comment: I think you need more specifics if you want a good answer.  If you search the site, you'll see the topic of modular exponentiation has been discussed in many previous Questions, and indeed the Wikipedia article has been referenced many times.

Answer (score 2):

$$5924\equiv2\pmod9\implies5924^{316}\equiv2^{316}$$

As $(2,9)=1,\phi(9)=6,316\equiv4\pmod6$

$$2^{316}\equiv2^4\pmod9\equiv?$$